# Is browser prefix still required for linear-gradient?

Tags: css

Do I still need to use the browser prefixes for the linear-gradient property?

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
```

I only want the support of latest browser versions. I tried following, but does not work.

```
background-image:    linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
```

Comment: Isn't the answer obvious, then?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/css-gradients

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out when I can safely drop vendor prefixes for a CSS3 property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211602/how-do-i-find-out-when-i-can-safely-drop-vendor-prefixes-for-a-css3-property) and [Do we have to use non-standard/browser specific CSS vendor prefixes anymore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401830/do-we-have-to-use-non-standard-browser-specific-css-anymore) (plus some similar questions linked in there)

Comment: @BoltClock, well, I thought may be there is some change in the syntax for the new browsers.

Comment: b.c. these are new they don't validate by W3...what a pain.

Comment: The problem in the example is that it's using the old syntax, which only works with prefix (at least in chrome).  So instead of "top", it should be "to bottom" which is the newer syntax and will work without prefix.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#search=linear-gradient), as of June 2017, 93.75% of Internet usage is on a browser that supports unprefixed linear gradients (97.2% in the US). For most people, this means you don't need to prefix your gradients anymore.

[image]

Below is the first compatible version and release date for the most common desktop browsers:

- IE v10, released September 2012
- Firefox v16, released August 2012
- Chrome v26, released February 2013
- Safari v6.1, released October 2013
- Opera 12.1, released November 2012

Information on compatibility history of other browsers (including mobile browsers) is available at [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#search=linear-gradient).

Answer (score 7):

You can now use:

```
linear-gradient
```

without prefixes and it will be supported by IE10+ as well as current versions of Safari, Chrome, and Firefox. For more detailed info see: 
http://caniuse.com/#search=linear-gradient

But short answer is: No prefix required.

Answer (score 0):

The following example

```
     background: rgb(238,238,238); /* Old browsers */
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%, rgba(238,238,238,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(238,238,238,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(238,238,238,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(238,238,238,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
     background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(238,238,238,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(238,238,238,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
     background: linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(238,238,238,1) 100%); /* W3C */
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#eeeeee', endColorstr='#eeeeee',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
```

shows that the linear-gradient is more beyond simple prefixes. For instance, the one that runs on IE requires a prefix and `DXImageTransform` object. Hence, `linear gradient` is more of an `SVG` attribute that requires some extra work beyond prefixes.