# Are vendor prefixes still needed in css Angular 6?

Tags: css

are vendor prefixes still needed with my sample css below? I am using angular 6.

```
 .container_2 {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
      transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
```

Comment: [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com) Basically, the answer depends on what browsers you're targeting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out when I can safely drop vendor prefixes for a CSS3 property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211602/how-do-i-find-out-when-i-can-safely-drop-vendor-prefixes-for-a-css3-property)

Comment: Thank u for informing me @jhpratt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vendor prefixes support depend on web browser's render engine. Angular is just a JS framework. CSS is outside of the scope

From my experience, most of Web browsers support popular syntax as `transform`, `box-shadow` without prefix already. If you want to sure, let check at https://caniuse.com/

If you don't want to care about those prefixes, let's use [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) [cssnext](http://cssnext.io/). These are polyfill tools that support newest specification of CSS. When the browser is fully supported new specs, CSSNext will automatically remove them for you

Comment: It's best not to answer duplicate questions.

Comment: @rj.learn Next time, please search. This is a blatant duplicate, and 30 second of searching would have given you the result.

Comment: @jhpratt noted 